# Avoiding using a loop to access a single post

Tags: loop

Sometimes I want to access one particular CPT to extract something from it, for example a custom field value:

```
$group = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'group',
    'p' => $group_id
) );
while ( $group->have_posts() ) : $group->the_post();
    $group_type = get_post_meta($post->ID, "group_type", $single = true);       
endwhile;
```

However the purpose of a loop is to access more than one element so I dislike using a loop for a single post. Is there a way to do exactly the same thing (accessing this custom field value) without using a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about [get_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post)?

```
$post       = get_post( $p );
$group_type = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'group_type', true );
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `WP_Query` object holds an array of posts. Just take first entry:

```
get_post_meta( $group->posts[0]->ID, "group_type", true );
```

Note: the third parameter for `get_post_meta()` expects a keyword: `true` or `false`, **not** `$single = true`. It works, but it looks rather odd. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use only *half* of a loop. Well, it's not even a loop, just the check if we received any post. Simply use the (WP_Query) objects methods. The example wraps it up in a function, so you could even use it as Template Tag:

```
function wpse83212_get_group_post( $group_id )
{
    add_filter( 'post_limits', 'wpse83212_group_post_limit' );
    $group = new WP_Query( array( 
         'post_type' => 'group'
        ,'p'         => $group_id
    ) );
    // Did the query return anything?
    if ( $group->have_posts() )
    {
        // Setup the post data
        $group->the_post();
        // Now we have access to the `$GLOBALS['post']` object
        // as well as to any functions that only work inside the Loop:
        return get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'group_type', true );
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}
function wpse83212_group_post_limit( $limit )
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__, 10 );
    return 1;
}
```

Then simply use it in any template: `$group_meta = wpse83212_get_group_post( 12 );`. If the value now is `NULL` there was no such post. Else you'd get the single value returned.

Comment: And perhaps also add `'posts_per_page' => 1` as argument to WP_Query, since OP only wants one post.

Comment: @webaware Good idea. But this will influence the per page limit only. I added an action for the `post_limits` filter.

Comment: Won't `'posts_per_page' => 1` do the same thing in effect, by returning only a single 'page' of 1 row from MySQL?

Comment: Afaik this depends on what page you're on, so it could be ... faulty.

Comment: Would specifying `'page_id' => 1` overcome that?